# How to use an Array of Sheet references for CountUnique

Tags: google-sheets

I have a lot of sheets that share the same format. I want to use `countUnique` on a column but want it to be dynamic (more sheets to be added)

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

`=COUNTUNIQUE('[A]'!L5:L, '[B]'!L5:L,'[C]'!L5:L, ...)`

But don't want to type each sheet name manually.

I tried to make a list of all the sheetnames with `concatenate` to make the format above and use `Indirect` to reference them but it doesn't work.

How do I do that?

Comment: _I tried to make a list of all the sheetnames with concatenate to make the format above and use Indirect to reference them but it doesn't work._ Please edit your question to show the formula that you tried.

Comment: The combination of these two question/answers from StackOverflow appear similar to the problem you are trying to solve. [How to use COUNTUNIQUE function within ArrayFormula and get a range result?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581305/1330560), and [Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846200/1330560).